# Which is a best jquery or javascript library for graph?I

Tags: javascript, jquery, protovis

I am using protovis. IE wont supports protovis. If there is a way to use graph in IE explain me or i need to know which is best js library for graph. Supported by all browsers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My final solution is best to use **Highcharts** .Its a jquery graph library easy to learn and efficient to use. All browsers support.

Answer (score 2):

For IE support I would use Flot:

http://code.google.com/p/flot/

The plugin works with Internet Explorer 6/7/8, Firefox 2.x+, Safari 3.0+, Opera 9.5+ and Konqueror 4.x+ with the HTML canvas tag (the excanvas Javascript emulation helper is used for IE).

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you CAN use protovis with IE, just not it's own.

The most popular solution lately is to use SVGWeb with protovis, the jloves protovis fork bundles it all together for you:

https://gitorious.org/protovis/jloves-protovis

But, the easiest and best behaving (in IE) solution is the bigfix protovis fork, which will render in VML (instead of SVG) when the user is in IE:

https://github.com/bigfix/protovis

Answer (score 1):

I strongly suggest you have a look at Raphaël JS :

http://raphaeljs.com/

As of today, the library supports Firefox 3.0+, Safari 3.0+, Chrome 5.0+, Opera 9.5+ and Internet Explorer 6.0+.

Answer (score 0):

[Google Chart API](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/index.html) lest you make a request to their servers to retrieve an image showing your graph - so works on all browsers. It just costs a little more bandwidth and perhaps time.

There is also their [Visualization API](http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/interactive_charts.html) for interactive JavaScript plotting.

Comment: Google graph is waste to use. dont prefer it.there is no accuracy in their graph